# RollupError: Could not resolve - vercel react vite deploy

Tags: reactjs, vite, vercel, netlify

Im trying to deploy my react vite project on vercel or netlify, but have an error:

```
RollupError: Could not resolve "./reviews/Reviews" from "src/components/Pages/CarDetails/CarDetails.jsx"
    at error (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2128:30)
    at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23782:24)
    at file:///vercel/path0/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:23744:26
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
Deployment completed
BUILD_UTILS_SPAWN_1: Command "yarn run build" exited with 1
```

here my vite.config.js:

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [react()],
    vite: {
        server: {
            watch: {
                usePolling: true,
            },
        },
    },
});
```

Google it, but still have no answer

Comment: It's saying that you have a file `src/components/Pages/CarDetails/CarDetails.jsx`  that is trying to import another file `./reviews/Reviews` and your app bundler `rollup` is not able to find it. I would try running the program locally first and see if the `CarDetails.jsx` file is able to load the `Reviews` component or whatever that is.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, this says "src/components/Pages/CarDetails/CarDetails.jsx" is trying to import "./reviews/Reviews" file but can't find it.

Just go to "CarDetails.jsx" component and check import statement of "./reviews/Reviews" casing (Uppercase and lowercase) is correct or not. if not correct then fix it. Because these things might work fine with your local machine but it gives problem in vercel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it was related to importing .jsx files from .tsx when tsconfig.json compile_options is configured with:

```
"paths": {
  "*": ["*", "*.tsx"]
}
```

you can change this config to what you want to be autodetected while compiling.