# Vercel deployment failing 'Could not resolve "./src/components/main-menu" from "index.tsx"'

Tags: build, vite, vercel

I have a Vite / React Electron app that I'm also trying to host on Vercel. I'm able to build/run the app locally. When trying to deploy the app from my GitHub repo to Vercel I'm running into the following build error:

`error during build: RollupError: Could not resolve "./src/components/main-menu" from "index.tsx" at error (file:///vercel/path0/packages/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:2287:30) at ModuleLoader.handleInvalidResolvedId (file:///vercel/path0/packages/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24855:24) at file:///vercel/path0/packages/app/node_modules/rollup/dist/es/shared/node-entry.js:24817:26 Error: Command "vite build" exited with 1`

Few screenshots of app:

[Main-menu component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKVqH.png)
[index.ts in main-menu subfolder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cuz8I.png)
[Main Menu import that build is complaining about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vruRC.png)

I tried updating my tsconfig.json like this post said https://stackoverflow.com/a/76345076 but not sure exactly how to edit nor did this change anything.. I don't have a Vite.config.js in my app directory not sure if that's part of the issue.